# Convert base64 image to text in php

Tags: php, base64

Say I have an image like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEcAAAArCAYAAAAqhpU+AAAEhElEQVRo3u2aXUhbZxjHf8YoQTQppYJkY6gRDaJDdJ3VBqfvoCJs0IuFwVjrWmfbCV4o3my7cZYxNlScsIldCHilg+lwUpmsC0VM2WDOoKIo82KCYmQGPWqQmY9deCLxO6bOmo8HzkWek/c95/zf//PJA1E5UmKCXWixWB4AXwJqn04IERNO4CiDAEUPfAcYDrntfR7Aj3ie9yz3O80BKk/xkkrgE+BTID6ECRHwASoDBKZYZkt2JPkc5QmgqGW/cg9Q+PRTU1NkZ2dHLjgWi+Um8A2g9ek2NzcxmUz09/djsVjO/WWFEBeGOT/6/7BarbS1tbGysiIBH8vAhVSEPfNo5XA4aG9vZ3h4GOAn4CNg8QWCcyGY43n8+LGio6MDp9O5BNQCP0SSQ1Ycc6+spaXF43Q6TUBWpAFzLHOEEMNAGTAcqeWD4oT7EQtMIOAQBScqUXD+96r8IojFYrkGGIFrQDpwCXABDmAZ+BP4FXgihHBEBDipqamYzebfgdeP+Esi8ArwGnDP4/H8Ozg4aFapVJ8JIZbC2qw6Ozs5BpiDH6dQxKtUqgfb29t/m0ym22HNnLi4OABsNhsjIyPYbDYcDgeSJJGYmEhycjIFBQWUl5eTlpbmvy4+PT29q7m5+Y2GhoaqsARnYWGB1tZWxsbGAJ7KxfFTYEmSJIckSZfm5uZe7u3tvWE0GuuqqqpSYmNjd9fn5+ffraysVHR1dd0JK7OamZmhpqaGsbGxv4A35ey9HRiXnbAL+Aewud3ur3p6el7q7u5+tH8fo9H4QUFBwd2wYI7c8/X1kf8AyuWodJJ4zGbz/aKiIq1Op3vLp0xISMBgMHSOjo7+LHcXQp45MfJ1NUBgdkWn091yuVwef11FRYUyJSXlYcQngUKIVa/Xu6ejEB8fT05Ozm3gSsRnyHFxcUP7dXl5eUrgRrR82PFVeyQjIwPZsUc8OAeyY41GA5AXBQdWjwAn6nOO+c4oOPgNO+xSaXU1dJPAfQMEGiGE9Bzbafcr1tbWkDPr0GZOdXX12mGnfwo5UMnPzs4ilxuhDU5ubi7sNLWClQMhe3R0FHaaYqENTllZGRw+DxSIeV4Bbvrrtra2fOD8EhbMMRgM94Nc/gX75on6+/vZ3Nx0Ak/CIlrV1tbmFBYWvnNK1rwHfOiv29jYoLu7G+Dbw/KfkGpZ+CQ5OZm6urrvFxcX366vrx88ARQl0AB87q93u900NjYiSdIqO3NHJ7YCAg2nZ9GXCTaU7xFJkp6p1epO4De5NHACl4FUuZi8s9+Bu91umpubGRoacgEVJ5nUeTPntMOU161Wq7WoqAiFYq/1q9XqYqA40I3sdjtNTU1MT0+7gOpAgLnQZiWEeAZcz8zMfFhaWipKSkrQarWn2sNut9PX18fAwABbW1vzwLsy2wKSmABP/Kwk2KmsTKBKr9e/r9frtVlZWeh0OjQaDUlJScTGxrK+vo4kSSwvLzM5Ocn4+DgTExN4vd554GvgEbBxHi/7IiVPznmuAq/KxeNl2Qoc8jUPWNmZEhkBPME86D8yB3ZQ6rfzGAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

Is there any other possibility to read the actual text of this (it's a simple number), other than saving it as an image and running it through some OCR library?

Comment: `"The actual test of this (it's a simple number)"` - No it isn't.  There is no "actual text".  It's an image.  OCR libraries exist for the purpose of extracting text from text-like images.  But the image itself *has no text*.  Human intuition may tell you that it's a picture of a number and the human brain is very good at discerning these things.  However, PHP is not a human brain.

Comment: I don't like why this question is getting downvotes, what is wrong with stackoverflow?

Comment: Because base64 is a method of encoding data not a magical tool of Detecting something in a text. you question could be equivalent to "detect if base64 image has a picture of a goat in it". Encoding could be binary, hexa, octa or deci, either way if you knew what encoding is you wouldn't ask this question. That;s why i assume you got so many downvotes.

Comment: bitmapa != tekst `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, only OCR. There is no actual text inside an image, only bits representing pixels and their colors.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't agree more with you on the "wtf is wrong with people". For the record it seems that I did indeed ask a very stupid question - at least in the downvoters eyes.